# how to import highcharts sub modules in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, charts, highcharts

I've been using the [react-jsx-highcharts](https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts/) module, to integrate [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) into my React app.

Works great. Now I want to include the [boost module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module). I'm not sure how to do this. I tried simply adding `import 'highcharts/modules/boost'` but this doesn't seem to work.

Anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: `highcharts-more` and `modules/boost` work the same way :) So yes, use the same `require(...)(Highcharts)` and it will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of the `highcharts` module (not `react-jsx-highcharts`) and is explained in its [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm):

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/boost')(Highcharts);
```

Alternatively, you can use `import` like so:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import boost from 'highcharts/modules/boost';
boost(Highcharts);
```